# How to use asp.net web api in Android

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

Can anybody help me How to use Asp.Net Web API in Android?

I want to create an android app using asp.net web api. I have to login using url something of this kind 
www.example.com/api/myproject?userid=somevalue&password=123.
Once login button clicked it will display a New page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTTPClient library that java has:
Here is an example:

```
// HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "<loginUrl>";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        if(response.equals("login_seccuss")){
           //move to next page
        }

    }
```